# Android non-native sip

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, sip

I am developing a app that uses non-native sip to signalling. I want to know how my app will be notified when a sip call arrives. I know that in general I can send braodcast with intent and catch that with a receiver. The native sip works like that. But with a non-native, how can I achieve that? I need to create a custom receiver? And how do I send the Intent? Can I serialize the intent in a json?

Comment: That would be something you need to include in your SIP implementation. You'll need to handle the `INVITE`s as they arrive.

Comment: I see that, but how android knows that arrived the INVITE?

Comment: You're the one who implemented your SIP, so *you* should know that.

Comment: I still understand that. Bau when my app is not running, something need to warn it that arrived an event(INVITE). It's like a push notification. I know that I can create a receiver that catch notification form Google GCm. I would like something similar, using just the sip, similir to native sip.

Comment: You don't need push notifications, that's why you have SIP. That's what SIP does for you. If you don't understand where to receive `INVITE` packets, then you either didn't write your own non-native SIP (as you claim) or you were unconscious while you were doing it. Are you possibly using a library?

Comment: I am using sip library, called resiprocate.

Comment: Then check the documentation there.

Answer (score 0):

On android, application may be suspended (the device is going to deep sleep) for short periods, but it's still possible to have them running regularly.

First, your java application should implement a Service. This will allow your application to run in the background:

Implement your Service in YourSipAppService.java: 
(and start it from your GUI code)

```
public class YourSipAppService extends Service
```

In Manifest:

```
    <service
        android:name=".YourSipAppService"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </service>
```

Then, you can use [startForeground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)), to put your service in a "foreground state" (this tells android to not kill the service)

Using the above, your application will always be active even without a GUI. Handle the native sip stack from this Service so you can access the SIP messages.

Then, you'll got to solve issue related to deep sleep. In practice, even when the device is inactive, it will still check sockets regularly and your app will receive the INVITEs. In order to maintain connectivity, your SIP application should use only connected protocol (ie: TCP, TLS, not UDP)

When doing SIP exchanges or calls, you can activate lock to ask the system to maintain power at least for the duration of the SIP transactions, or the complete SIP calls:

```
mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
int wifi_mode = WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 12)
    wifi_mode = 3; /* WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF */
mWifiLock = mWifiManager.createWifiLock(wifi_mode, "com.yoursipapp.wifi");
if (mWifiLock != null)
    mWifiLock.setReferenceCounted(false);
```

Then, when you requires to have full wifi power:

```
mWifiLock.acquire();
```

And when you do not require it any more:

```
mWifiLock.release();
```

In order to announce the call, you need to turn on the device and display an activity on top of the keyguard. Various API needs to be used, this may depends on the Android version you wish to support. Here is some code showing how to setup and acquire a Screen Lock and a Keyguard Lock that can be added to your Service:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
mScreenWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK |
                                 PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                                 PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, 
                                 "YourSipAppServiceKeepScreenActive");
mScreenWakeLock.setReferenceCounted(false);
mKeyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
mKeyguardLock = mKeyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("com.yoursipapp.unlockforincomingcall");
```

You will acquire this lock when receiving a call:

```
mScreenWakeLock.acquire();
if (mKeyguardLock != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
    mKeyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
}
```

Then, in the Activity which answer calls, you can also add this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

  ...
}
```

To conclude, once you've done all that, you can popup your incoming call Activity:

- Your Activity will appear above the keyguard.
- The phone/device will be turned on when receiving a call.
- The wifi will have full power, when needed!